# How to make the state/region optional in Magento 2.0.7?

Tags: magento2, checkout, country-regions

In a Magento 2.0.7 with very little customization when we disable a country in `State is Required for` in `Stores -> Configuration -> General -> State Options` the state field in the checkout process shows up as non required field for this country. However, when we try to proceed without selecting a state this is not possible and we get the error message

> Please select an option.

below this field. If we select a state we can proceed.

This kind of feels like a bug, maybe it's just a rogue javascript validator? How can we make the state field in the checkout truly optional? And do we face a individual problem or a common bug here?

Also worth mentioning, the `Allow to Choose State if It is Optional for Country` option has no noticeable effect for us.

Comment: In my case (Magento 2.1) the State/Region field is optional by default and I'm struggling to make it mandatory. This is so random.. :/

Answer (score 4):

To either make the State option MANDATORY or OPTIONAL, as of Magento 2.2.x, you set the option at: **STORES**>>**Configuration**>>**General**>>**State Options**[image]